# Why does Worksheet_Change only fire when in developer mode?

Tags: excel, vba

Weird bug i am having and i can't seem to solve it, i have the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    MsgBox "change"
End Sub
```

This should fire on my sheet every time a cell is changed however no msgbox appears until i click back onto the developer mode, then it fires. Only ever if i click on developer mode it will fire x amount of times i made a change on the worksheet.

I tried this on a new sheet and it works perfectly. Is there something that would prevent a change of cell function working properly? I can't understand why it wouldn't run until i enter my developers page.
As far as i understand Appliation.EnableEvents is set to True.

Just to clarify:
This function only runs when I click onto developer mode. Kind of feels like it queues up and then fires once I enter developer mode.

Answer (score 0):

Right click your sheet and paste in the following code sample.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("A1:C10")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been
        ' changed.
        ' Place your code here.
        MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."

End If
End Sub
```

Remember, this is Sheet code, and NOT Module code.

Comment: I will give this a go when I get home, I am starting to believe that it’s more of a bug than anything else, related to how my other code runs. If this doesn’t work I will have to recreate my code slowly and see what’s causing it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'developer mode'. Right click the sheet that you want to run the code in, click 'View Code', and paste your code, or my code, into the window that opens. That's it.